# Changing the audioTimePitchAlgorithm parameter for an AVPlayerItem

Tags: ios, audio, swift2, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm trying to change the audioTimePitchAlgorithm for playback at lower rates than 0.5 but don't seem to be having much luck. I've scoured SO for solutions but every implementation I try seems to still limit me to a rate of 0.5 or above...

```
var player: AVPlayer = AVQueuePlayer()

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    let assetQueue = [aVItem1, aVItem2, aVItem3, aVItem4, aVItem5, aVItem6, aVItem7, aVItem8, aVItem9, aVItem0]

    var itemQueue: [AVPlayerItem] = []

    for index in 0...9{

        let nextItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: assetQueue[index])

        nextItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = "AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral"

        itemQueue.append(nextItem)
    }

    player = AVQueuePlayer(items: itemQueue)

    player.play()

    player.rate = 0.25

}
```

I apologise in advance if this is actually a straight forward process and I am perhaps too new to this to grasp some of the underlying concepts. I have already also tried creating an AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters object and assigning it to an AVMutableAudioMix object and intern assigning this mix object to the AVPlayerItem, but this also yielded the same result (playback at a rate of 0.5), so I have only included my first, more simplified, code attempt. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Haha, what a peanut!? Figured it out, just needed `nextItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral`